# Run an R script from any folder with a batch file

Tags: r, batch-file, ggplot2, cmd, automation

I tried to 'automate' plotting out data from an excel file by having a batch file ask for the file path. I am far from experienced at what I'm trying to achieve.

Currently I use the following R-script:
The quality of the code might be poor, but it is not the reason for my question.

```
#install.packages("readxl")
#install.packages("ggplot2")
#install.packages("dplyr")
#install.packages('ggthemes')
### Load packages
library('ggplot2')
library('scales')
library('readxl')
library('dplyr')
library('ggthemes')
cat("Please write folder path: ")
Excel <- readLines(con = "stdin", n = 1)

df <- read_excel(Excel,col_names = FALSE, sheet = 1) 
df <- df[c(3:9),c(1:14)]
id <- as.data.frame(df[1, colSums(is.na(df))==0])[,-1]


cat("Please write ouput path: ")
Excel_out <- readLines(con = "stdin", n = 1)
p <- 0
Data <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 5, nrow = 5))
colnames(Data) <- c(df[2,3:6],"Type")
#3-6, 7-10, 11-14
for (i in seq(3,11,4)) {
  p <- p+1
  tmp <- as.data.frame(sapply(df[3:7,i:(i+3)],as.numeric))
  colnames(tmp) <- df[2,3:6]
  tmp$Type <- rep(as.character(id[p]),5)
  tmp$AC_conc <- sapply(df[3:7,2],as.numeric)
  assign(as.character(id[p]),tmp)
  Data <- na.omit(full_join(Data,tmp))

### ads over COD ###
  CODt <- ggplot(tmp,aes(x = tmp[,1],y = tmp[,4])) +
    geom_point() + geom_line() +
    labs(x = "Concentration (mg COD/L)", y = colnames(tmp)[4]) + # + theme_bw() + xlim(120,220) + ylim(0.01,0.2)
    theme_excel_new() + scale_colour_excel_new() + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(), axis.title.y = element_text())
  ggsave(paste("CODt" , as.character(id[p]),".png"),
         plot = CODt,
         scale = 1.5,
         width = 80,
         height = 60,
         units = "mm",
         path = Excel_out)
### ads over AC concentratie ###  
  AC <- ggplot(tmp,aes(x = tmp[,6],y = tmp[,4])) +
    geom_point() + geom_line() +
    labs(x = "Concentration of activated carbon (mg/L)", y = colnames(tmp)[4]) + 
      theme_excel_new() + scale_colour_excel_new() + 
    theme(axis.title.x = element_text(), axis.title.y = element_text())
  ggsave(paste("AC" , as.character(id[p]),".png"),
         plot = AC,
         scale = 1.5,
         width = 80,
         height = 60,
         units = "mm",
         path = Excel_out)

}
### Combination plots ###

COD_layered <- ggplot(Data,aes(x = Data[,1], y = Data[,4], group = Type)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=Type)) + geom_line(aes(color=Type)) + labs(x = "Concentration (mg COD/L)", y = colnames(tmp)[4]) +
  theme_excel_new(base_family = "sans") + scale_colour_excel_new() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(), axis.title.y = element_text())

ggsave("COD_layered.png",
       plot = COD_layered,
       scale = 1.5,
       width = 80,
       height = 60,
       units = "mm",
       path = Excel_out)

AC_Layered <- ggplot(Data,aes(x = Data[,6], y = Data[,4], group = Type)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=Type)) + geom_line(aes(color=Type)) + labs(x = "Concentration of activated carbon (mg COD/L)", y = colnames(tmp)[4]) +
  theme_excel_new(base_family = "sans") + scale_colour_excel_new() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(), axis.title.y = element_text())

ggsave("AC_layered.png",
       plot = AC_Layered,
       scale = 1.5,
       width = 80,
       height = 60,
       units = "mm",
       path = Excel_out)
```

The batch file

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.2\bin\Rscript.exe" C:\Users\Bob\Documents\Rfiles\Script.R
pause
```

To try and make the use of this code 'universal', so able to work from any folder, I have made it ask for the full file path, which is very primitive and inefficient. I read that the folder path to the batch file can be called upon by %0, but I'm not sure how to implement this in a way the R file will also get this information. Ideally the user would only have to input the excel file name and the name they want the final files to have, but due to no experience with cmd or coding outside of R, I'm stuck.

I have implemented a bad and inefficient method of finding the folder path a script has to be run.

Comment: There's really no shortcut here. However, if you accept the path name as an *input parameter* instead of asking for it interactively, you can drag & drop the folder onto your batch file icon in the File Explorer, instead of having to enter it via the keyboard.

Comment: Or, alternatively, navigate to the folder containing your input file and then call the batch file with an absolute/local path (or shortcut).